# Sending Emails in Laravel using emails from users table

Tags: laravel, email

Hello guys am stuck here!

```
public function updateResponse(Request $request)
    {

        $response = SupervisorResponse::find($request->id);
        

        try{
            $response->update($request->only('response'));
            flash('Response has been updated!');


        }catch (Exception $e){
            abort(500, 'Oops something went wrong!');
        }
         
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SupervisorResponseEmail($user,$response));

        return back();
    }
```

When I hardcode the email i.e like this

```
Mail::to('demo@demo.com')->send(new SupervisorResponseEmail($user,$response));
```

the email goes, but when I use email of a user from database it fails and brings an error

> "Trying to get property 'email' of non-object"

May you please help me guys.

Comment: show the output of dd(gettype($user));

Comment: Make sure that `$request->user_id` is set, use `dd($user);` to make sure you got a User model